# How to add condition to HTML code in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, vue.js

I have the following template code:

```
<template v-for="(index, message) in messages">
  {literal}
  <div class="message_block {{message.message_type}}" v-if="message.message_type">
    <div class="message">
      {{message.message}}
    </div>
  </div>
  {/literal}
</template>
```

What I'm trying to do is show the one line - `<div class="message_block"...`, if `message.message_type` is not equal to `null`, or is not `undefined`.

This is the data I've got:

```
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#testblock',
  data: {
    messages: [
      { message: 'Foo', message_type: "left" },
      { message: 'Bar', message_type: null }
    ]
  }
})
```

I'm trying to add the wrapper `<div class="message_block">`, if the `message_type` is not equal to `null`.

Comment: Looks good to me, what is it that is not working?

Comment: works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/9c3tdrpj/

Comment: Did you make any progress with that? @think123

Comment: @LinusBorg No, I want the "Bar" to show regardless of the value of `message_type`, it's just if `message_type` is `null`, I don't want a wrapper `<div>` around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment above:

> @LinusBorg No, I want the "Bar" to show regardless of the value of message_type, it's just if message_type is null, I don't want a wrapper  around it.

There is no other way than to duplicate the inner div.

```
<template v-for="(index, message) in messages">
  {literal}
  <div class="message_block {{message.message_type}}" v-if="message.message_type">
    <div class="message">
      {{message.message}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div v-if="!message.message_type" class="message">
    {{message.message}}
  </div>
  {/literal}
</template>
```

If you don't want to duplicate it, you can either define it as a small component to re-use it, or use a [partial](http://vuejs.org/api/#partial).

Comment: oh wow, ok... simply because I haven't delved deep into the development of  this component, would you have any recommendations for another JavaScript framework I can use, that would provide better templating functionality, and would suit my needs for a chat messaging component?

Comment: I am not aware of a framework (or template system) that would handle this much differently/better, no, mostly due to how HTML is strctured and DOM is created. handlebars, jade etc work like this also. Maybe in a React render function you would have more flexibility, but that's not a templating engine anymore, it's basically pure Javascript to build the DOM. I don't see this as a big problem though.

Comment: yeah, that would make sense now that I think about it... coming directly from just using Smarty I guess I expected the functionality to be similar, in regards to just outputting anything. I'm using my own handling system now, as it allows me more flexibility over my code.